# Code required to aggregate dataframe group total as well as retrieve first and last date by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I am using python for some supply chain/manufacturing purposes. I am trying to figure out some code that will allow me to do configure the relevant information I need to compile.

I am trying to aggregate the total 'UnitsProduced' by 'Lot' and also grab only the first occurring 'Date/StartTime' and last occurring 'Date/EndTime'.

Right now the (simplified) dataframe is as follows:

| Lot | UnitsProduced | Date/StartTime | Date/EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1/1/2021 8:00 | 1/1/2021 13:00 |
| 1 | 13 | 1/2/2021 10:00 | 1/2/2021 14:00 |
| 2 | 20 | 1/3/2021 7:00 | 1/3/2021 11:00 |
| 3 | 15 | 1/4/2021 14:30 | 1/4/2021 19:00 |
| 3 | 6 | 1/4/2021 20:00 | 1/4/2021 22:00 |
| 3 | 28 | 1/5/2021 7:00 | 1/5/2021 13:00 |

The end result should look something like:

| Lot | Units Produced | Date/StartTime | Date/EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | 1/1/2021 8:00 | 1/2/2021 14:00 |
| 2 | 20 | 1/3/2021 7:00 | 1/3/2021 11:00 |
| 3 | 49 | 1/4/2021 14:30 | 1/5/2021 13:00 |

Thank you for the help. If there is any other information I can provide please let me know

Comment: Please show a working piece of code you wrote yet about your trial to solve this problem, and give specific error messages or details you would like help about. So we can copy paste and reproduce, so it is easier to answer your question.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Copy that. I didn't even really know where to start on this solution so hadn't come up with code yet for it. I'll make sure for future posts I show my trial code no matter how poor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby.agg` with a dictionary of aggregate functions, just make sure that the date columns are in datetime format:

```
# df['Date/StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/StartTime'])
# df['Date/EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/EndTime'])
df.groupby('Lot', as_index=False).agg({'UnitsProduced':'sum',
                                       'Date/StartTime':'min',
                                       'Date/EndTime':'max'})

   Lot  UnitsProduced      Date/StartTime        Date/EndTime
0    1             18 2021-01-01 08:00:00 2021-01-02 14:00:00
1    2             20 2021-01-03 07:00:00 2021-01-03 11:00:00
2    3             49 2021-01-04 14:30:00 2021-01-05 13:00:00
​
```